# OllyDbg doesn't work in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, debugging, process, cracking, ollydbg

Windows 7 x64 & OllyDbg 1.10

I just start to learn debugging technology,
and try to debug a demo programm called 'crack_me.exe' using OllyDbg.
But I meet with a problem as follows:

I set a breakpoint in 'crack_me.exe' and press F9 to run the program,
but Windows alert a dialogue (My OS is in Chinese):
[image: Crack me crashh]

> General meanning:
> crack_me.exe has stopped work.
> Windows can connect to Internet and find a solution to this problem.
>
> - Connect to Internet to find a solution and close the program
> - Close the program
> - Debug the program

If I choose the 3rd option, then Windows say:
[image]

> General meanning:
> A debugger has attached to crack_me.exe, but the debugger isn't set to debug the unhandled exception. If you want to debug this exception, you must detach the current debugger.

I have chosen to ignore all exceptions Ollydbg settings, as shown in following figure:
[image]

I just want to know why this problem happens and how to fix it.
All replies are expected.
Thank you.

---

It's weird that today this problem happens again, even with the same app, crack_me.exe.
I DO NOT install any plugin this time but Windows still alerts that crack_me.exe(same as other apps) crashes.
Why yesterday Olly works normally and today the problem happened again ?

Comment: Did you solve at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you are running ollydbg as an administrator (I gave my olly exe admin privileges globally via the properties dialog in explorer).

Secondly, and most importantly, you also need to turn off inspection of SSE registers (which requires code injects that don't work under Windows 7/Vista WOW64), the setting for this can be access via the Options Menu -> Debugging Options (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>) -> Registers Tab -> Decode SSE Registers. I'd also advise taking off Decode Registers For Any IP, when once both these options where disabled, olly work for me under any Vista/Win7 kernel based OS).

Also, make sure you aren't using any plugins, most are not compatible with Windows 7 WOW64, but they should generally lead to crashes on starting olly, when you have olly working again, then one can add the plugins one by one, validating that they actually work.

Comment: Thanks to your reply, and I found you're right, it's the plugin.

Comment: It's weird that today this problem happens again, even with the same app, crack_me.exe. I DO NOT install any plugin this time but Windows still alerts that crack_me.exe(same as other apps) crashes. Why yesterday Olly works normally and today the problem happened again ?

Comment: @Memory: did you make sure to do the other two things I mentioned? also, I've noticed oddities under Win7 x64 with olly that requires the binaries to be replaced from time to time with fresh copies (mainly only loaddll)

Comment: Sure, I've checked for the 2 things you said above, but the problem remains. What do you mean "olly requires the binaries to be replaced from time to time with fresh copies" ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late answer :)) but for people who gets this error is the options under Debugging Options (ALT + O) -> Exceptions and uncheck "Single-Step break" and "Ignore also following custom exceptions or rages" ...

Answer (score 0):

OllyDbg works fine on Windows 7 x64 & 2008R2. It seems the problem lies with the crackme app - which is crashing.

Perhaps you should try olly with other 32-bit apps (notepad2 or other simple application) and see if olly is indeed the source of problem...

Comment: I tried notepad.exe and Windows also alert a dialogue as crack_me.exe:  www.flickr.com/photos/60494994@N05/7278740984/